# I am unable build up a query in Solr

Tags: solr, solrj, solr4, solrcloud

I am trying to form a query in solr for data import but could not able to do so.

I need to form the below query:
http://salsa23q-XXX-08.XXX.XXX.com:8080/solr/#/geoloc_replica1/dataimport/?command=full-import&clean=true

The code I am trying:

```
public class SolrJDB
{
    public static String url = "http://salsa23q-XXX-08.XXX.XXX.com:8080/solr:8080/solr";
    public static SolrServer localserver;
    public static CloudSolrServer cloudserver;// = new CloudSolrServer("url");
    public static SolrQuery que;
    public static SolrInputDocument doc;
    public static SolrDocumentList list;
    public static QueryResponse response;

    public static String serverurl = "http://salsa23q-XXX-08.XXX.XXX.com:8080/solr";

public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, SQLException, SolrServerException {
        try{
            System.out.println("+++++++++++++      Starting here       +++++++++++++++++++++");
            //Cloud Server
            String url = "salsa23q-XXX-08.XXX.XXX.com:8080/solr";
            cloudserver = new CloudSolrServer(url);
            SolrQuery parameters = new SolrQuery();
            parameters.set("qt","/geoloc_replica1");
            parameters.set("qt","//dataimport");
            parameters.set("command","full-import");
            System.out.println("Query to be Executed ============"+parameters.toString());
            QueryResponse response = cloudserver.query(parameters);
            SolrDocumentList list = response.getResults();
        }
        catch(SolrServerException e){
            System.out.println(e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


I am getting following error:

    org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: Error executing query
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.QueryRequest.process(QueryRequest.java:98)
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer.query(SolrServer.java:301)
        at SolrJDB.main(SolrJDB.java:37)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException
        at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient.<init>(SolrZkClient.java:115)
        at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient.<init>(SolrZkClient.java:83)
        at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ZkStateReader.<init>(ZkStateReader.java:138)
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CloudSolrServer.connect(CloudSolrServer.java:140)
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CloudSolrServer.request(CloudSolrServer.java:165)
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.QueryRequest.process(QueryRequest.java:90)
        ... 2 more
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up things in your code. You want to perform a request to run a DataImportHandler. But you are constructing a SolrQuery. The latter represents a search request.

What you need to run a DataImportHandler via the Java API is an [`UpdateRequest`](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/request/UpdateRequest.html).

```java
public int runDataImportHandler() throws Exception {

    // fill in the parameters you want to run your import with
    ModifiableSolrParams tmpParams = new ModifiableSolrParams();
    tmpParams.set("command", "full-import");
    tmpParams.set("clean", true);
    tmpParams.set("commit", true);
    tmpParams.set("optimize", true);

    // create the update request
    UpdateRequest tmpRequest = new UpdateRequest("/dataimport");
    tmpRequest.setParams(tmpParams);

    SolrServer tmpServer = getServer();
    tmpRequest.process(tmpServer);

    ModifiableSolrParams tmpStatusParams = new ModifiableSolrParams();
    tmpStatusParams.set("command", "status");
    String tmpStatus = "busy";
    int tmpProcessed = 0;
    do {
        System.out.println("waiting for import to finish, status was " + tmpStatus);
        Thread.sleep(500);

        UpdateRequest tmpStatusRequest = new UpdateRequest("/dataimport");
        tmpStatusRequest.setParams(tmpStatusParams);
        UpdateResponse tmpStatusResponse = tmpStatusRequest.process(tmpServer);
        tmpStatus = tmpStatusResponse.getResponse().get("status").toString();

        Map tmpMessages = (Map) tmpStatusResponse.getResponse().get("statusMessages");
        System.out.println("import status is " + tmpStatus);
        if (tmpMessages.get("Total Documents Processed") != null) {
            tmpProcessed = Integer.valueOf(tmpMessages.get("Total Documents Processed").toString());
        }
    } while ("busy".equals(tmpStatus));

    System.out.println("import done");

    return tmpProcessed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I can see your code the exception is related to how CloudSolrServer instance is created :-

To make instance of CloudSolrServer you need to have Solr in Cloud mode and the URL used here will be zookeeper address. CloudSolrServer creates zkStateReader which gets live nodes and collection from which it query.

Following is the exact way how you would be creating the code for dataimport:-

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws SolrServerException, IOException {

    ModifiableSolrParams params = new ModifiableSolrParams();
    params.set(UpdateParams.COLLECTION, "collection1");
    params.set(CommonParams.QT, "/dataimport");
    params.set("command", "full-import");
    params.set("claen", true);
    params.set(UpdateParams.COMMIT, true);
    params.set(UpdateParams.OPTIMIZE, true);
    String url = "localhost:9983"; /*Zookeeper Address*/
    CloudSolrServer cloudserver = new CloudSolrServer(url, true);
    cloudserver.setDefaultCollection("test");/*This is necessary in case if you are not specifying any collection name in dataimport*/
    cloudserver.query(params);
}
```